# Mpdf stripping html formatting

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm playing with Mpdf for generating some html as a PDF but HTML tags don't seem to be working

I'm using Mpdf 7.1.6 and PHP 7.2

I can include stylesheets or not with no difference

```
$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(["format" => "A4"]);

$pdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Heading 1</h1>');
$pdf->WriteHTML('<h2>Heading 2</h2>');
$pdf->WriteHTML('<h3>Heading 3</h3>');
$pdf->WriteHTML('<h4>Heading 4</h4>');
$pdf->WriteHTML('<b>Bold</b>');
$pdf->WriteHTML('<center>Center</center>');
$pdf->WriteHTML('<table><tr><td>Table</td><td>Table</td></tr><tr><td>Table</td><td>Table</td></tr></table>');

$pdf->Output();
```

and I get the following
[image]

Not sure what the issue is.
Had to install Mpdf manually as I'm on a shared server and don't have command access nor access to composer so it could be a missing library of config file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as it's doing my head in.

Comment: What happens if you do `$pdf->WriteHTML('<h4 style="color:red">Heading 4</h4>');`

Comment: @Chris Haas It's still black, not red.

Comment: When you say that you installed it manually, do you mean you just downloaded it and wrote your own auto loader, or did you use composer locally and then FTP’d those files up?

Comment: u can try `$myDom = htmlspecialchars_decode('<h4 style="color:red">Heading 4</h4>'); $pdf->WriteHTML($myDom);` or `$pdf->WriteHTML("$myDom");`

Comment: @ChrisHaas Still black.

Comment: I downloaded mpdf and the other libraries it used and manually built an include file to put it together.

Comment: My recommendation, as well as [mPDF's official recommendation](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/using-without-composer.html), is to use composer and install it locally, then FTP it up. That'll guarantee you have everything at least.